# Adding/removing classes with jquery

Tags: jquery, class, addclass, removeclass

I am trying to change the font size of a webpage. I have specified three sizes:

- Small
- Medium
- Large

Based on what the user clicks the html font size should become the size he chooses.

`#small`, `#med`, `#large` are three paragraph elements.

`medium`, `small`, `large` are three classes for CSS.

My code is:

```
enter code here



<script>
                $(document).ready(function(){
                    $("#small").click(function(){
                        if($("p").hasClass('large'))
                        {
                         $("p").removeClass("large").addClass("small");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            $("p").removeClass("medium").addClass("small");
                        }
                        });
                    $("#med").click(function(){
                        if($("p").hasClass('small'))
                        {
                            $("p").removeClass("small").addClass("medium");

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            $("p").removeClass("large").addClass("medium");
                        }

                    });

                    $("#large").click(function(){
                        if($("p").hasClass('small'))
                        {
                            $("p").removeClass("small").addClass("large");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            $("p").removeClass("medium").addClass("large");
                        }

                    });


                });
            </script>
```

I don't think its working perfectly. So if anyone could show where i am going wrong will be of great help.

Comment: You could save some lines by removing multiple classes at once... `.removeClass("small medium")`  If you want to write better jQuery, **read the jQuery docs**:  http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/

Comment: So one problem is if they click small, you never remove large.

Comment: "I don't think its working perfectly" doesn't say what problem you are observing.  You should describe exactly what the problem is you're having.  You get javascript errors?  Or what do you observe that is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are a bit verbose, for each click there is no need for any decision, you always have to remove any of the other two classes and add the one from the button you pressed

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#small").click(function(){
        $("p").removeClass("medium").removeClass("large").addClass("small");
    });
    $("#med").click(function(){
        $("p").removeClass("small").removeClass("large").addClass("medium");
    });
    $("#large").click(function(){
        $("p").removeClass("small").removeClass("medium").addClass("large");
    });
});
```

You could probably "compress" that further by using the `id` as a variable using something like the following (note that the click-able element is "#med" and the class is "medium", so that would need additional work)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#small,#med,#large").click(function(this){
        $("p").removeClass().addClass($(this).attr("id"));
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @dualed :) I appreciate your help. Do you know any good material for me to start to learn jquery. I am new to it and i find it very interesting.

Comment: Sorry, I only use the [jQuery API docs](http://api.jquery.com), they are very detailed though.

Comment: ok.. i will use them too.. i am currently learning from w3schools

Comment: w3schools is not known as a good resource, I'm not sure about their jQuery articles (did not even know they had them), but for Javascript/DOM they are known to contain errors. There is even an Anti-w3schools site out there (w3fools.com)

Comment: Thanks again. I should start to use the jquery api and learn i guess thats the best way to learn.

Answer (score 0):

A bit more compact way would be to combime the classes as below:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#small").click(function(){
        $("p").removeClass("medium large").addClass("small");
    });
    $("#med").click(function(){
        $("p").removeClass("small large").addClass("medium");
    });

    $("#large").click(function(){
        $("p").removeClass("small medium").addClass("large");
    });
});
```